# How to set/access state from different component/file (React)

Tags: reactjs, typescript, react-hooks

I cannot seem to get my head around sharing states between components. So far I have tried:

SelectionMenu.tsx

```
...
import { FeatureMenu } from "./FeatureMenu"
...
export const SelectionMenu: React.FunctionComponent = () => {
    const history = useHistory();
    const [selected, setSelected] = useState<string>("");
    const onSelected = (value: string) => setSelected(value);

    return (
        <SubMenu size="half">
            <SubMenuHead>
                <SubMenuTitle>Selection</SubMenuTitle>
                <Status>{selected}</Status>
            </SubMenuHead>
            <SelectList>
                <MenuHead className="sub-menu-heading">Select</MenuHead>
                    <CategoryButton onClick={() => history.push(SomeUrls.FeatureMenu)}>
                        A Category
                    </CategoryButton>
                <FeatureMenu onSelected={onSelected} />
            </SelectList>
        </SubMenu>
    );
};
```

FeatureMenu.tsx

```
type Props = {
    onSelected: (value: string) => void;
};

export const FeatureMenu: React.FunctionComponent<Props> = ({
                                                                  onSelected,
                                                              }) => {
    const history = useHistory();
    const selections = useAppSelector((state) => state.selection.list);
    const feature = useMemo(
        () => uniq(selections.map((m) => m.aFeature)),
        [selections]
    );

    const handleClick = (value: string) => {
        onSelected(value);
    };

    return (
      <SelectMenu variants={selectMenu} initial="hidden" animate="visible" exit="hidden">
        <SelectList>
            <MenuHeading className="select-menu-heading">Feature</MenuHeading>
            {feature.map((f) => (
                    <SelectListButton
                        key={`${f}`}
                        onClick={() => handleClick(`${f}`)}
                    >
                        {`${f}`}
                    </SelectListButton>
                ))
            )}
        </SelectList>
      </SelectMenu>
    );
};
```

If the code looks odd it's because I edited the original code to appear more generic. SelectionMenu.tsx is a sidebar menu and FeatureMenu.tsx is a second sidebar menu and extends out from the first menu when a category is chosen. However, when I click on a SelectListButton from the second menu, I get the error: 'Uncaught TypeError: onSelected is not a function
at handleClick'. I'm not sure how to pass onSelected correctly and I'm not very familiar React or with states between components, and trying to learn. Thanks for any help in advance

Tried code and expected to select a feature in the second menu FeatureMenu and for the contents of the SelectListButton to appear in the Status element of the first menu SelectionMenu

Comment: Hello @emH , could you replicate your code in codesandbox? I've made something similar and it's working: https://codesandbox.io/s/stoic-sun-p03kh3?file=/src/SelectionMenu.tsx

Comment: Try onClick={() => onSelected(`${f}`)} instead of handleClick

Comment: It might be a weird bug, but you are not closing your parentheses properly in your `feature.map((f)`, it has one parentheses too much. What happens if you'd change `))` to `)` (right below the `</SelectListButton>`)